# Can I override a class in the classpath?

Tags: java, tomcat

Ok, here is the issue.  We are using an old version of Tomcat (6.0.35) because our version of linux (ubuntu 12.04) doesn't have a repository with a newer version of it.  Unfortunately, there is a bug in 6.0.35 that is affecting us ( https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53725 ).  IT doesn't want to/can't change tomcat versions. They want to use the package management system, they don't want to rebuild tomcat.  They can't maintain something like this on a whole bunch of servers and we don't particularly want to disable Gzip.  We can deal with the corruption until we can finally upgrade.

So with that background, the real question. The changes which fix this bug reside in one single class.  We came up with a crazy solution (which will probably never see production, but was more of a "this would be so terrible, lets try it!" sort of idea), How about we compile the fixed version of the class and hotswap it in.  After all, tomcat and our project use the same JVM.

Is this doable/possible/more than a little crazy?

Some hurdles.  We are using Java 6.  The new class adds methods and fields. I'm not sure that tomcat keeps it around.

Comment: It sounds possible but you said it best: "this would be so terrible, lets try it!'. This kind of `ClassLoader` tinkering is always pretty rough.

Comment: It certainly isn't a great solution, it just sounded so bad that we wanted to see if it was even doable :).  The right solution is updating tomcat.

Comment: Download the tarball, extract, configure and run.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is unreasonable to actually do. The only way to cleanly unload a class and then load a replacement is to let the ClassLoader used to load that particular class be garbage collected. This will require you to remove all references to any of the classes that ClassLoader loads (which is probably at least all of TomCat) and reload them using a ClassLoader that loads all classes like normal, except for the class you 'fixed'. You would have to make it so that it loads that class instead of the old one, while still allowing the other classes to load normally.

In short, it is possible, however it will require digging into java ClassLoaders. I'd recommend that you do not actually attempt this, as it will be very annoying to get right and it will certainly not work without shutting down the TomCat server first (since you have to reload all of TomCat's classes).

Comment: What about `IntrumentationInstance` ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html ) could that be used to do the magic? Specifically "redefineClass". Or does that only work if the Object is created from the new class definition?

Answer (score 0):

Who is doing the unzipping, Tomcat or the application? If its the application, just make a copy of the class in error to the root of your project classpath in src/main/java and put there the patched version of the class.

Upon packaging the patched class will be in WEB-INF/classes, and override the version in the server. But its overridden only from the point of view of the application, the server cannot see the patched version and still sees the buggy version.

If its tomcat itself that needs to unzip something, then its not possible to fix that without tinkering with the server.

But if its the application doing the unzipping its for sure possible, there is no obligation to use the libraries of the server we can use our own more updated copies, usually not in patches but in jars in WEB-INF/lib - the server is designed for that.

Comment: Sadly it would be the server that needs to do the unzipping.  The program never directly uses the Gzip class that is in error.

Comment: then there is no way without messing with the server. application classes cannot override the ones the server uses, if nothing else for security reasons, this is by design